# How can I make the function $\cot (z)$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I make the function $\cot (z)$ holomorphic?

$\cot (z)$ clearly has a pole whenever $\tan (z)=0$. This happens when $z=n\pi$, including at $(0,0)$.

Is it possible to define a branch such to make $\cot (z)$ holomorphic? 
Is it possible to define the domain of holomorphicity?

This function is used to derive identities such as $\sum 1/n^2$

Comment: Do you mean *entire*? For what it's worth, $\cot$ is already holomorphic in its domain.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, entire, do I need a branch cut along the $y$ axis, if so what should I do with the $0$?

Comment: No $\cot z = 1/\tan z$ needs no branch cut.  When $\tan z = 0$, $\cot z$ has a pole, and when $\cot z = 0$, $\tan z$ has a pole.  On the other hand, you *will* need a branch cut for $\arctan z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers with $x_n\to0$, then $\cot x_n\to+\infty$. This shows $\cot z$ cannot be bounded near the origin, and an entire function must be bounded on bounded sets.